# what is the different between building server side VS API

Tags: javascript, express, npm

so currently i am studying web development but the course was a little bit confusing, the teacher starts explain promise object and fetch then axios, after that he starts to talk about the "express" package to build server side, and am asking myself what is the different between using API objects & building server side using express?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those things work together to create a website/app. axios, etc runs in the browser (client-side code), and is used to send requests to the server (express/other server-side code), allowing the server to fetch data, or modify the database, and return a response back to the browser side code, which continues operating from there.

imagine, client-side code does not have access to your server's database, as your database is on the server, and the browser is on the end user's computer. The two sets of code send messages back and forth to each other to create an app that has a centrally stored data store that is "shared" between users.